Insert dictionary in dataframe row under same column
I am trying to insert a dictionary into a dataframe row under a column. However, it inserts subsequent dictionaries as a list. If I dont't insert dictionary within a list I get a "Incompatible indexer with Series" error.
df = pd.DataFrame()
fields = list(IC_data['data']['initialData'].keys())
for field in fields:
    df.loc[field, 'Field Name'] = field

    if field == 'keyExecutives':
        List1 = IC_data['data']['initialData']['keyExecutives']
        List2 = IC_data['data']['encomFields']['keyExecutives']
        List3 = IC_data['data']['legalFields']['keyExecutives']
        # Combine all lists into a single list
        all_lists = [(1, List1), (2, List2), (3, List3)]
        matched_dict = best_Listmatch(all_lists,field)
        count = 0
        for match, (name,score, x, y) in matched_dict.items():
            print(matched_dict.items())
            if x==1 and y==2:
                df.loc[field+str(count),'Encom'] = [{'Encom Field value': match,'Match Score - DV_Encom' : score*100}]
            elif x==1 and y==3:
                df.loc[field+str(count),'DN'] = {'DN Field value': match,'Match Score - DV_DN' : score*100}
            elif x==2 and y==3:
                df.loc[field+str(count),'IC'] = {'DV Field value': match,'Match Score - Encom_DN' : score*100}
            count += 1
        

My matched_dict is in the form of,
dict_items([('CASH, JOHN 1971-02', ('CASH, JOHN 1971-02', 1.0, 1, 3)), ('ABRA, JUNE 1968-10', ('CASH, JOHN 1971-02', 0.71, 1, 3))])
x and y refers to last 2 values in  ('CASH, JOHN 1971-02', 1.0, 1, 3)
Getting my output as
  {
    "Field Name": null,
    "Encompass": null,
    "DNB": {
        "DNB Field value": "CASH, JOHN 1971-02",
        "Match Score - ICDV_DNB": 100
      }
  },
  {
    "Field Name": null,
    "Encompass": null,
    "DNB": [
      {
        "DNB Field value": "ABRA, JUNE 1968-10",
        "Match Score - ICDV_DNB": 71
      }
    ]
  }

In the second dict above, its getting enclosed under a list whereas the the first dict is not getting enclosed under a list. I want all dict items to be stored as a dict only under a dataframe row, ie, for example under, df.loc[field+str(count),'IC']
